# php download files not working on mobile

Tags: php

```
if (file_exists($file)) {                                 
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename. "." . $exts );
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

this code works on pc, but on mobile i can not open the file. The headers is incorrect?

Comment: What happens when you try to download it?

Comment: Which mobile device did you use?

Comment: @colmde I have an error message "can not open file".

Comment: @StefanGehrig Asus zenfone and Sony

Comment: *"cannot open file"* doesn't mean the download is not working. It can mean the OS doesn't know what app to use to open it. This usually happens because no app is registered to handle the file's extension. Sending the correct `Content-Type` could also help (`application/octet-stream` is a generic content type; the best the browser can do with it is to save the file and do not attempt to open it).

Comment: @axiac yes, but I don't have a specific file type. maybe a PDF , it can be a txt .. or another . This is why I put it generic

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

After

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename. "." . $exts );
```

Comment: thanks, but this code not working. it not even download the file